# Marvel Contest of Champions - Hero Probability

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

Is there a way to influence what hero I'll get in the "roulette" system when I'm opening crystals? Or is it completely random?

Answer (score 1):

It is random. There is no way to manipulate your luck when opening crystals. You will hear the most amazing theories on how someone can get 4* heroes easily, but of course they are not true.

The most popular hoaxes, as far as I know, are:

- if everyone from your alliance opens them at the same time you get a better chance of opening a 4*.
- if you tap a arena crystal after 9 seconds of spinning you'll get units more often
- if you buy too many crystals you'll actually lower your chances of winning good rewards

Again, those are all speculative theories on the internet, Kabam have denied them all. Don't forget

> The plural of anecdote is not data.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, its all luck of the draw.

I have heard that if you open lots of 10 you are meant to have a better chance at a 4 stars. I seem to have better results from opening bulk crystals of all types.